# Is it possible to copy to clipboard using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a sharepoint webpart which has a button pull elements from different text boxes on the same page and collates them together in a single string to then copy to the user's clipboard so they can quickly put together a communication for an issue.  So far I have the below code, but it's not actually copying anything.  I've run it through JSHint and that's not turned up any issues, but I picked up the code at the bottom of the function for copying the text from a tutorial about interacting with the clipboard API for how to copy from a text box, hence why I add everything to the smsToSend text area.  A note for people is that if there's an issue that's brand new and hasn't been sent out before, then the incident update is always 'we are investigating the issue' as this is automatically placed into the field, which is why I testing against it, as both new and update communications would have 'Open' as the incident status.

```
function generateSMS(){
 var issueTitle = document.getElementById("incidentTitle");
 var advisorImpact = document.getElementById("advisorImpact");
 var incidentUpdate = document.getElementById("incidentUpdate");
 var incidentStatus = document.getElementById("incidentState");
 var startTime = document.getElementById("startTime");
 var endTime = document.getElementById("endTime");
 var smsToSend = document.createElement('textarea');
 var incidentPriority = document.getElementById("incidentPriority");
 var incidentBrand = "TechTeams";
 var systemImpacted = document.getElementById("systemImpacted");
 var incidentReference = document.getElementById("incidentReference");

 if (incidentStatus != "Closed"){
     if (incidentUpdate == "We are investigating this issue"){
         smsToSend = "P" + incidentPriority + " " + incidentBrand + "IT ISSUE: " + systemImpacted + ": " + issueTitle + ". " + advisorImpact + ": " + incidentReference;
     }
     else {
         smsToSend = "P" + incidentPriority + " " + incidentBrand + "IT UPDATE: " + systemImpacted + ": " + incidentUpdate + ": " + incidentReference;
     }
 }
 else{
     smsToSend = "P" + incidentPriority + " " + incidentBrand + "IT RESOLVED: " + systemImpacted + ": " + incidentUpdate + ": Start: " + startTime + " End: " + endTime + " Reference: " + incidentReference;
 }

 smsToSend.setAttribute('readonly','');
  smsToSend.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
  document.body.appendChild(smsToSend);
  smsToSend.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(smsToSend);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easly copy to clipboard with js like so:

```
function CopyToClipboard(text) {
    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("elementId").textContent; //here you get the text
    var dummy = $('<textarea>').val(copyText).appendTo('body').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');//here the text gets copyed
    alert("Text copyed to clipboard!");
    $(dummy).remove();// here you remove the dummy that has been created previously
}
```